# Any way to disable time sensitive parameters thru the 0x api to get consistent encoded tx data?

Tags: 0x

Friends, I have noticed that the encoded tx data for any given params you get from the 0x api changes second to second. I noticed it does this even when I hardcode the same salt. I assume this is because of time-sensitive parameters like guaranteed price and so forth. Is there any way to send a request to the API that will always give me the same encoded tx data?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is dependent on the chain state there will always be variability as prices and liquidity move.